# Scala - Creating a function to produce Unary string or integer values

Tags: scala

Hello fellow Scala programmers,

I have a question or need assurance that this is the correct why to write a function which can only return the values "+", "-" or 1, -1. I'm basically creating a unary function which can return 1 or -1 for arithmetic purposes and "+" or "-" display purposes depending on the parameters passed. Here's the code...

```
package testit

object testit {

  abstract class UPairs[T]{
    def getFirst():T
    def getSecond():T
  }

  class UString() extends UPairs[String]{
    def getFirst():String = "+"
    def getSecond():String = "-"
  }

  object UString {
    def apply() = new UString()
  }

  class UInt() extends UPairs[Int]{
    def getFirst():Int = 1
    def getSecond():Int = -1
  }

  object UInt {
    def apply() = new UInt()
  }

  abstract class Unary
  case class Positive() extends Unary
  case class Negative() extends Unary

  def unaryFunc[T](u:Unary, p:UPairs[T]):T = {
    u match {
      case Positive() => p.getFirst()
      case Negative() => p.getSecond()
    }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    println(unaryFunc(Positive(), UString()))
    println(unaryFunc(Negative(), UInt()))
    println(unaryFunc(Positive(), UInt()))
  }

}
```

Note: The above code works and produces the correct results and restricts the input to valid parameters.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this the correct way to write a unary function which can only return the values "+","-" or 1, -1 depending on if you want strings or integers?

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll have to go with this solution.

```
package exprP

object ExprObj {

  abstract class UPair[T] {
    def getPositive():T
    def getNegative():T
  }

  object UString extends UPair[String] {
    def getPositive():String = "+"
    def getNegative():String = "-"
  }

  object UInt extends UPair[Int] {
    def getPositive():Int = 1
    def getNegative():Int = -1
  }

  abstract class Unary
  case class Positive() extends Unary
  case class Negative() extends Unary

  def unaryFunc[T](u:Unary, p:UPair[T]):T = {
    u match {
      case Positive() => p.getPositive()
      case Negative() => p.getNegative()
    }
  }

}
```